# Using data value in an onchange event in a HTML form

Tags: html, html-select, onchange

I am creating a sort of calculator in which a person will select two values and the corresponding earnings will be calculated. A person will select from a drop-down list of values against the fields "Wage by Employer" and "Effort by Worker". The fields that needs to be calculated are "Employer Earning" and "Worker Earning".

"Employer Earning" is straight forward to calculate it is given by formula 
`$(120-Wage)*Effort$`. However Worker Earnings is slightly complicated because for each value of "Effort", there will be corresponding "Effort Cost", user will never select "Effort Cost" but the relationship between Effort and Effort Cost is predetermined. "Worker Earning" is given by the formula $Wage - 20 - Effort Cost$. 
Now I have written the following code to create this earning calculator;

```
<form name="earning_calculator">
<body>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Earnings Calculator</legend>
</fieldset>

<table width="" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="col">Wage by Employer</td>

      <td><select id="Line_One" name="Line_One" onchange="
      document.getElementById('value1').value=this.value;
      document.getElementById('e_earning').value = (120 - document.getElementById('value1').value) * document.getElementById('value2').value;
      this.value = this.value.toFixed(2);
      this.value='$' + this.value;
      document.getElementById('w_earning').value = (document.getElementById('value1').value -0) - 20 -
      document.getElementById('value3').value
      document.getElementById('w_earning').value = document.getElementById('value1').value - 20 - document.getElementById('value3').value">
          <option value="" selected="selected"> Select </option>
          <option value="20"> 20 points </option>
          <option value="25"> 25 points </option>
          <option value="30"> 30 points </option>
          <option value="35"> 35 points </option>
          <option value="40"> 40 points </option>
          <option value="45"> 45 points </option>
          <option value="50"> 50 points </option>
          <option value="55"> 55 points </option>
          <option value="60"> 60 points </option>
          <option value="65"> 65 points </option>
          <option value="70"> 70 points </option>
          <option value="75"> 75 points </option>
          <option value="80"> 80 points </option>
          <option value="85"> 85 points </option>
          <option value="90"> 90 points </option>
          <option value="95"> 95 points </option>
          <option value="100"> 100 points </option>
          <option value="105"> 105 points </option>
          <option value="110"> 110 points </option>
          <option value="115"> 115 points </option>
          <option value="120"> 120 points </option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="col">Effort by Worker</td>
      <td><select id="Line_Two" name="Line_Two" onchange=
      "document.getElementById('value2').value=this.value;
      document.getElementById('value3').value = this.getAttribute('data-cost');
      document.getElementById('e_earning').value = (120 - document.getElementById('value1').value) * document.getElementById('value2').value;
      document.getElementById('effort_cost').value = document.getElementById('value3').value;
      document.getElementById('w_earning').value = document.getElementById('value1').value - 20 - document.getElementById('value3').value">
          <option value="" data-cost="" selected="selected"> Select </option>
          <option value="0.1" data-cost = "0"> 0.1 </option>
          <option value="0.2" data-cost = "1"> 0.2 </option>
          <option value="0.3" data-cost = "2"> 0.3 </option>
          <option value="0.4" data-cost = "4"> 0.4 </option>
          <option value="0.5" data-cost = "6"> 0.5 </option>
          <option value="0.6" data-cost = "8"> 0.6 </option>
          <option value="0.7" data-cost = "10"> 0.7 </option>
          <option value="0.8" data-cost = "12"> 0.8 </option>
          <option value="0.9" data-cost = "15"> 0.9 </option>
          <option value="1" data-cost = "18"> 1 </option>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  <fieldset>

  <input type="hidden" id="value1">
  <input type="hidden" id="value2">
  <input type="hidden" id="value3">

    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="label-container">
        <p><label for="e_earning">Employer Earning</label></p>
        <p><label for="w_earning">Worker Earning</label></p>
        <p><label for="effort_cost">Effort Cost</label></p>
      </div>
      <div class="input-container">
        <p><input type="text" id="e_earning" name="e_earning" placeholder="0.00 readonly" disabled></p>
        <p><input type="text" id="w_earning" name="w_earning" placeholder="0.00 readonly" disabled></p>
        <p><input type="text" id="effort_cost" name="effort_cost" placeholder="0.00 readonly" disabled></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

</body>
</form>
```

The problem with the above code is in the way I am extracting effort_cost, specifically in the line `document.getElementById('value3').value = this.getAttribute('data-cost');` under an onchange event. This line is not picking the corresponding "Effort Cost" as I want it to do. I will appreciate any help on this.

Comment: You have to do something like `this.options[this.selectedIndex]...get attribute`. Right now you're trying to get an attribute of the `select`, not the `option`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comment above.

```
document.getElementById('value3').value =
    this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-cost');
```